# Are temporary lvalues a use case for std::move

Tags: c++, move-semantics, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

I have a `class` like this:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(A const& a) { /* do something */ }
    Widget(A&& a) { /* do something */ }
};
```

Which I can use like this:

```
A a{};
Widget widget{a};
```

If I came to the conclusion that I don't need `a` any longer, I could call:

```
Widget{std::move(a)};
```

---

But now what if I needed an `A` object only for the construction of `widget`? Would I do this:

```
Widget widget{A{}};
```

or

```
Widget widget{std::move(A{})};
```

Comment: I can't see any "temporary lvalue". `A{}` is an rvalue, so it overload resolution will pick up the move constructor.

Comment: I think you meant to write `Widget widget{std::move(a)};` in the *or* case.

Comment: Then how come `A{} = A{};` is a valid expression?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Do you think an rvalue cannot appear on the left side of an equation and because `A{} = A{}` is valid that must mean that `A{}` is not an rvalue? In that case forget about rvalue and lvalue in the sense of left and right of an assignment, that just doesn't hold in C++.

Comment: @hgiesel: This being C++, it wouldn't surprise me were that to turn out to be a declaration :P

Comment: @nwp: `int(42) = 43;` "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" Whether or not it applies here, such a rule _does_ exist.

Comment: In fact, this is interesting: `int{42} = 43;` "error: using temporary as lvalue" heh. Anyway, I think it only works because `A` isn't a built-in.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet yes you can call non const methods on rvalue objects, `operator=` is not an exception

Comment: @nwp exactly that, I know lvalues needn't always be on the lhs, but I thought you couldn't assign rvalues

Comment: @hgiesel: You can't assign to rvalues of built-in types (don't forget the "to" in that sentence). But `A` is a class so the rules are substantially more relaxed.

Comment: As far as why `A{} = A{};` works see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897799/temporary-objects-when-are-they-created-how-do-you-recognise-them-in-code

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet In all honesty `int{42} = 43;` should compile. There is no good reason to allow `Int{42} = 43;` and disallow `int{42} = 43;` besides *"nobody thought it was important enough to change it in the standard"*.

Comment: @nwp It is because built in types are not class types so they do not have member functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver That doesn't make sense. It could still be allowed without member functions. It is a language design thing.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet techincally `A{} = A{};` can be treated as `A{}.operator=( A{} );`

Comment: @Slava: Yes, thank you, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary is an rvalue; there are no "temporary lvalues". `Widget widget{A{}};` will call `Widget(A&& a)` as `A{}` is a temporary. `std::move` is used when you have an lvalue and you want to make it an rvalue like you do with:

```
A a{};
Widget widget{std::move(a)};
```

Another reason to use it would be if you are in a function that takes an rvalue and you want to move it to the constructor.  With the function

```
Widget foo(A&& a);
```

`a` is a lvalue in the body of the function.  If you want to convert it back to an rvalue then you would need to use `std::move` like

```
Widget foo(A&& a)
{
    Widget widget{std::move(a)};
}
```