# C++ function return value category for operator overloaded function?

Tags: c++, lvalue, rvalue

In the code sample below, un-commenting the line `// fun() = 1;` would result in a compile error as `fun` returns an rvalue. What I don't understand is why the line `(B1 + B2) = B0;` does not result in a compile error? Isn't overloaded operator semantically same as function call? In that case `B1 + B2` also should return an rvalue, so shouldn't this result in compile error too?

```
#include<iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int X = 0;
};

Base operator+(Base b1, Base b2) {
    Base b;
    b.X = b1.X + b2.X;
    return b;
}

int fun () {
    int x;
    return x;
}

int main () {
    //  fun() = 1;

    Base B0,B1,B2;
    (B1 + B2) = B0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: B1 + B2 yields a Base so why would you not be able to assign to it another Base?

Comment: @Ian because it should be an rvalue

Comment: @Ian `fun()` yields an `int`, why would you not be able to assign an int to it? Thats the whole question. The commented out line complains about needing an lvalue, `(B1 + B2) = B0` compiles even though `operator+` for Base returns an r-value.

Comment: My personal guess is that, 1) you can't assign to rvalues (by definition, rvalue are on the right side of assignments), 2) `Base` is using an overloaded `operator=`, not assignment. So it's just a normal function, which can be called on rvalues

Comment: The short of it is that the language permits you to modify rvalue class types, e.g. via member functions such as assignment operators.

Comment: I know `operator=` is not explicitely overloaded, but I think the compiler generated `operator=` works the same

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897799/temporary-objects-when-are-they-created-how-do-you-recognise-them-in-code

Comment: To prove my point, try declaring `operator=(const Base&) & = default`. It won't work with rvalues

Comment: I agree with @Borgleader, thus my updated answer.