# Pointers Confusion in C++

Tags: c++

I am confused by the slides in my c++ course. On the one hand in Example 1
   int(*foo)[5] is a pointer to an integer array of 5 elements, but in Example 2
   int(*numbers2)[4] points to an array of arrays (4 arrays) of type integer.    How can these two have the same lefthand declaration but hold different types?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main() {

    //Example1
    int numbers[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int(*foo)[5] = &numbers;
    int *foo1 = *foo;


    //Example2 
    int numRows = 3;
    int(*numbers2)[4] = new int[numRows][4];
    delete[] numbers2;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `numbers2` points to the *first element* of the dynamic array. That's now `new` expressions work.

Comment: Think a little... If you allocate a plain array of integers then `new int[numRows]` return `int*`. So when you allocate an array of array you get a pointer to an array, or `int (*)[4]` (in your specific case).

Comment: An `int*` can point to a single integer or to the address of the first element of an array of integers. Same is true of a pointer to an array. It can point to a single array or the address of the first element of an array of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [pointer declaration reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer):

> Because of the array-to-pointer implicit conversion, pointer to the
>   first element of an array can be initialized with an expression of
>   array type:
>
> ```
> int a[2];
> int* p1 = a; // pointer to the first element a[0] (an int) of the array a
>
> int b[6][3][8];
> int (*p2)[3][8] = b; // pointer to the first element b[0] of the array b,
>                      // which is an array of 3 arrays of 8 ints
> ```

So essentially speaking what lefthand `numbers2` and `foo` point to on the right hand side matters.

So in following `numbers2` point to first element of [temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897799/temporary-objects-when-are-they-created-how-do-you-recognise-them-in-code) (yet unnamed) array which is an array of `numRows` arrays of 4 ints

```
 int(*numbers2)[4] = new int[numRows][4];
```

While `foo` points to first element of `numbers` which is an array of 5 ints

```
int(*foo)[5] = &numbers;
```

Answer (score 2):

The description in your question of example 2 is not exactly correct.

Try phrasing like this and you will see the parallelism.

- `foo` is a pointer to the first object, each object is an integer array of 5 elements.  (As it turns out, the first one is the only one)
- `numbers2` is a pointer to the first object, each object is an integer array of 4 elements.  (As it turns out, there are a total of `numRows` of them)

A pointer data type doesn't tell you the number of objects it points to, only the type of each one.